# How to handle routes with image extensions

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, routes

I have action:

```
public ActionResult Thumbnail(string image)
{
     return GetThumbnail(image);
}
```

I am trying to access it with the next request:

```
http://localhost:60955/thumbnail/imagename.png
```

In config I have:

```
<add name="Png" path="/thumbnail/*.png" verb="GET" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
```

And in routes configuration:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Thumbnail",
    url: "thumbnail/{*image}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Image", action = "Thumbnail" }
);
```

So it works for the above image URL. But I need this to work for any subfolder and the following returns 404:

```
http://localhost:60955/thumbnail/screenshots/imagename.png
```

And when I add slash it works again:

```
http://localhost:60955/thumbnail/screenshots/imagename.png/
```

> Can I make it work with no trailing slash?
>   I feel like I need to customize the handler path in the config but cannot figure out how.

Answer (score 0):

You should use query string for this case

URL change to this

```
http://localhost:60955/thumbnail?image=screenshots/imagename.png
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that I need to do that without question mark and ampersand. So just this style: http://localhost/thumbnail/50/100/~/folder1/folder2/image.png. This is a third party limitation. So I need to capture everything after thumbnail/